# How to test click event using pure javascript and Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a really simple increment function in vanilla javascript.

This function have a button with a click event, which triggers the input to sum one to its value.

I've tried to search for help to think how to resolve this problem. I think maybe I should create a mock for the button (instead of access the DOM element), and simulates the click event with Enzyme (but I don't know if it is really necessary).

All I could get in my searches was Jest testing using components from React or Angular, which complicated much more my question and therefore I get no answer for simple JS. The Jest documentation didn't help either.

The code of my function is:

```
const increment = () => {
  $increment.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (+$quantity.value < 100) {
      $quantity.value = +$quantity.value + 1;
    }
  });
};
```

The full code is on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frontend-bianca-pereira-2syvt).

Answer (score 2):

Hokay so, my JavaScript is a little rusty but I think I know the problem looking at the code (thank you by the way, it made this way easier to figure out)...

Your instinct that you need a mock is correct, but right now the way your `increment` function works it's coupled to `$increment` which is in the local scope (making it really unfun to mock). Instead of using a private variable in the local scope to bind the event listener to, you want to pass the `$element` into the `increment` function, and then to add the event listener to it.

```
const increment = ($element) => {
  $element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (+$quantity.value < 100) {
      $quantity.value = +$quantity.value + 1;
    }
  });
};
```

In your test now you can create a mock with a function on it called `addEventListener`... the below is probably not quite right, but I think should get you most of the way there:

```
// In your test setup, or in the test itself

const myMockElement = {
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
};

// Later in your test

increment(myMockElement);

expect(myMockElement.addEventListener.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Just as a note from the code in the event listener, I'd recommend passing it `$quantity` into the function as well instead of capturing it from the local context/scope/whatever-the-hell-its-exactly-called-in-javascript (i.e. what we did with `$element`)... it'll make testing things MUCH, MUCH easier to test and make your functions more robust.

Hope this helps!